How to work with back and forward when I use pushState?
I use pushState to change url.
But with this method of changing the URL, I can't normally work with back and forward. Is Is there a way to make pushState work with back/forward just like with routing router.push(url)?
history.pushState(null, document.title, response.filter?.filterUrl);

We can subscribe on popstate event and load the necessary data inside it, but for some reason this option only works once. Then popstate reloads the page.
onMounted(() => {

            window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
                getData();
            });
        });

I work with nuxt.
